# getting error 404 The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am just doing the data flow in which is not working properly.
the code is like the following :

index.jsp

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>    
    <form action="add">
      <input type = "text" name  = "t1"><br>
      <input type = "text" name  = "t2"><br>
      <input type = "submit">    
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>shivam</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>shivam</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.springmvc</groupId>
  <artifactId>First_Spring_MVC_project</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>First_Spring_MVC_project Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.20</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>First_Spring_MVC_project</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

while i created an java class where the code is written.
AddController.java

```
package com.springmvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class AddController
{
    @RequestMapping("add")
    public void add()
    {
        System.out.println("i am here");
    }

}
```

and shivam-servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">


    <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.springmvc"></ctx:component-scan>
</beans>
```

error :

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Type Status Report Description The origin
>   server did not find a current representation for the target resource
>   or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.34

Answer (score 0):

Remove your

```
<ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.springmvc"></ctx:component-scan>
```

add

```
<!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvc" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

..
After that make sure that in your WEB-INF folder, create view folder, and in that folder put your jsp page ( index.jsp )

After that
change your controller from

```
@Controller
public class AddController
{
    @RequestMapping("add")
    public void add()
    {
        System.out.println("i am here");
    }

}
```

to

```
 @Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
    public class AddController
    {
        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String add()
        {
            System.out.println("i am here");
    return "index";
        }

    }
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>spring-mvc-crud-demo</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering />

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/shivam-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

your
shivam-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvc" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Make sure that your web.xml, shivam-servlet.xml, and view folder are located in WEB-INF